# Is it possible to receive my visa sticker from another embassy than my home country

Tags: visas, germany

I have applied for the German national visa at my home country and waiting for the result. I am planning to take a trip to another country.

Assuming my visa is approved while I'm abroad, is it possible to receive my visa sticker from the German embassy at that country?

Comment: Are you planning to go straight to Germany from this other country if your visa is granted? If not, why bother?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Yes I want to go to Germany from there

Comment: Interesting question I am very interested in experiences here

Comment: They are unlikely to allow. Did you try calling the embassy?

Comment: @AnishSheela not yet. I thought I'd check here first to see anybody has such experience